# Checking proof for Omega Notation

Tags: proof-writing, notation, asymptotics, computer-science

I am checking if the below statement is true. However, it is true where n is assumed to be 1 but not when it is greater than 1. In this case, I do not need to think about if c is not 0. Would I consider this statement to then be valid?

2^n/n^1000 ∈ Ω(n^1000000)

Answer (score 0):

Let's look at the definition of $\Omega(f)$:

$$ \Omega(f) = \{ g \mid \exists c \text{ such that } c\cdot g(n) \leq f(n) \textbf{ almost everywhere} \} $$

That "almost everywhere" means "from some value of $n$ on". Sometimes you may have seen this written as $\exists c, n_0$ such that $c\cdot g(n) \leq f(n)$ for $n \geq n_0$.

So what you have to do is a limit, and notice that, for all real $c$:

$$ \dfrac{2^n \cdot c}{ n^{1000} \cdot n^{1000000}} \to_\infty \infty \cdot c = \infty $$

That is, $2^n$, even divided by a polynomial, still "grows faster" than any polynomial.

So there is no $c$ such that $\dfrac{2^n \cdot c}{n^{1000}} \leq n^{1000000}$ almost everywhere.